# play reactivemongo error after upgrade to 0.11.0

Tags: playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I just upgraded play reactivemongo from 0.10.5.0.AKKA23 to 0.11.0.play24. However, i got the following error with the code which compiles fine before the upgrade.

```
val gridFS = new GridFS(db)
val file = gridFS.find(BSONDocument("filename" -> new BSONString(name)))
serve(gridFS).map(_.withHeaders(CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> "inline;"))
```

Error Message

```
[error]  required: reactivemongo.api.gridfs.GridFS[play.modules.reactivemongo.json.JSONSerializationPack.type]
[error] serve(gridFS).map(_.withHeaders(CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> "inline;"
```

Answer (score 0):

The new plugin 0.11 is providing ReactiveMongo API with the JSONSerializationPack (allowing to work with JSON valued in coast to coast approach).

Thus the `serve` action in the Play Mongo controller is working with a GridFS API using this same JSON serialization (and expect `JsValue`/`JsObject` but not `BSONValue`/`BSONDocument`).

First step is to use the `reactiveMongoApi.gridFS` instead a the `new GridFS` (considering `reactiveMongoApi` being the API instance resolved as indicated in the documentation). The GridFS instance is properly initialized for the use with JSON.

Then the query selector must be updated from `BSONDocument` to `Json.obj`.

An example can be found in the [sample app](https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-demo-app/blob/master/app/controllers/Articles.scala).